# Can the arguments be named as desired when usign native code in Codename One?

Tags: ios, objective-c, codenameone, native-code

I need to write native code to delete a picture from the camera library. I am completely new to Objective C so I get a bit confused by the following lines found in Codename One developper guide :

> Objective-C relies on argument names as part of the
>   message (method) signature. So -(NSString*)helloWorld:
>   (NSString*)param
>    isn’t
>    the
>    same
>    as
>    -
>   (NSString*)helloWorld:
>   (NSString*)iChangedThisName !
>   Don’t change argument names in the Objective-C native interface!

Does it that `public boolean deleteFile(String path)` in java has to be written `(BOOL)deleteFile: (NSString*) param` in my Objective C native code ?

Or does it mean that the parameter names in the interface file (.h) and in the implementation file (.m) have to be identical ?

Thanks a lot to anyone making it clearer in my mind ;-)!

Cheers

Comment: I've noticed you didn't accept the answers for most of  the questions that were answered correctly. Please do as it helps the person answering, provides you with additional points and provides a better answered question ratio to the tag.

Comment: Sorry my connection has been intermittent for a week. But I will!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to keep your java argument's name in your Obj-C files. 
Otherwhise , it wouldn't be recognized as an implementation of NativeInterface.

 And it's simple to maintain the interface.

Comment: Correct. Objective-C considers the argument name as part of the method signature which makes this pretty difficult to map in any way that makes sense. You can't change those after the fact.

Comment: Thank you. So from the java interface to the Obj-C native code, the same argument names have to be used.